# How can I map different JSON inputs to the same object in RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, json, model, internationalization, restkit

I'm modeling without problems normal JSON objects, but now for internationalization I want to model the following scenario where an attribute could be a string or a dictionary of key/value pairs:

```
"objects": [{"title": "non internatinalizaed title", ...},
    {"title": {"en": "english string", "es": "spanish string"}, ...},
    ....]
```

Since I don't know if the server is going to send a single string or multiple strings I was thinking of creating a model object like this:

```
@interface I18NString : Object
@property (copy) NSString *forced; // Set when there is no i18n
@property (copy) NSDictionary *strings; // Set with i18n.
- (NSString*)stringValue; // Returns forced or one of strings
```

Similar to a C struct union, depending on `strings` being not nil I would choose one property or the other in the `stringValue` method. I've read the [Dynamic object mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping) section in the restkit wiki but I fail to see how could I use it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to model is a 1 to many relationships, where many could be 500, 1 or 0. So, it's ok the server sends an NSDictionary with only one key/value (or even 0, although I guess your many relationship is 1..n instead of 0..n)